# HTML Formular redirects to XAMPP localhost Home-Page

Tags: php, html, forms, redirect, xampp

So, here I am again with another Problem -.-'

I programmed my own php/html script to give in and pass data from a form to a database. At the beginning it worked. Somehow, some days later it started redirecting me to the XAMPP localhost homepage (http://localhost/xampp/). I've got no idea why :/

Here's how my website looks like:

- index.php

  - all other scripts (via Switch-case)
  - including my guestbook-scripts (no switch-case!) It's always there!

Here's how my "addguestbook.php" looks like:

```
   <?php

...database stuff...

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $website = $_POST['website'];
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
    $datetime = date("l, jS M Y, g:i a"); //date time

    // Connect to server and select database.
    mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)or die("cannot connect server: ".mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($db_name)or die("cannot select DB: ".mysql_error());

    $sql="INSERT INTO ".$tbl_name."(id, name, email, website, comment, datetime)VALUES('".$post_id."', '".$name."', '".$email."', '".$website."', '".$comment."', '".$datetime."')";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    mysql_close();

    header('Location: http://'.$hostname.$path.'/index.php' . $get, true, 303);
}?>

<form action="index.php<? echo $get; ?>" method="post">
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td class="guestbookFormCell" colspan='2'><input
                class="guestbookInputFieldText" name="name" type="text"
                value="Name *" size="40" maxlength="30" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="guestbookFormCell" colspan='2'><input
                class="guestbookInputFieldText" name="email" type="text"
                value="E-Mail (won't become displayed)" size="40" maxlength="40" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="guestbookFormCell" colspan='2'><input
                class="guestbookInputFieldText" name="website" type="text"
                value="Website" size="40" maxlength="50" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="guestbookFormCell" colspan='2'><textarea
                    class="guestbookInputFieldText" name="comment" cols="37" rows="5">Comment *</textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- 
        <tr>
            <td>CAPTCHA</td>
        </tr>
         -->
        <tr>
            <td><button class="guestbookFormCell guestbookButton" type="submit"
                    name="submit">
                    <span class='guestbookButtonText'>Send</span>
                </button></td>
            <td><button class="guestbookFormCell guestbookButton" style="float:right;"type="reset"
                    name="reset">
                    <span class='guestbookButtonText'>Reset</span>
                </button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

in index.php:

```
                $get = "?mod=home";
```

This script is used for several stuff: overall gueastbook of the page and for comments on single posts & pictures/albums.

PS: i couldN't write hello at the beginning of the thread, for some reason :/ If that came over rude, i'm sorry!

PSS: Got the error.

Pretty dumb :)

I simply forgot that the forum is actually redirecting to (in this case) index.php in the root-directory. That means to Xampp/htdocs/index.php.

I just gotta fix the link and I'm fine -.-'

Comment: `PS: i couldN't write hello at the beginning of the thread, for some reason :/ If that came over rude, i'm sorry!` Joke of the day... :)

Comment: The word 'Hello' was unnecessary. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92382/how-come-each-time-i-start-a-question-with-dear-ladies-and-sirs-this-greeting

Comment: +1 for the joke of the day on question

Answer (score 2):

Just edit or delete the orginal index.html and remove the following line

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/xampp/">
```

Best would be if you also clean your cache, because the your browser is forecd to load everyting new.

endo

*EDIT*: Youre not alone with that problem: [why-does-my-xampp-installation-auto-redirect-to-http-localhost-xampp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320205/why-does-my-xampp-installation-auto-redirect-to-http-localhost-xampp)

Answer (score 0):

I am glad you did find what the problem is, as I can't actually understand how you script works, however, when assigning the $name, $email, $website, etc, you must use the mysql_espace_string(). Otherwise, a user could inject malicious code and have access to the whole SQL table.

```
$name = mysql_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$email = mysql_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$website = mysql_escape_string($_POST['website']);
$comment = mysql_escape_string($_POST['comment']);
$datetime = date("l, jS M Y, g:i a"); // Escaping the string is not necessary here.
```

(Sorry for any language errors: I am not a native english speaker.)

Comment: Better yet, use parameterized queries (via PDO).